# Setting an Outlook mailitem's category programmatically?

Tags: outlook, office-interop

There doesn't seem to much information or any good code samples for setting an Outlook 2007 MailItem's categories programmatically.

[MSDN has a limited page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.categories.aspx), and mentions using VB's **Split** function, saying more or less "*you're on your own from here onwards, so sort it out yourself*".

So far as I can tell we manipulate the Categories as a comma delimited string property of the mailitem. It seems a bit primitive, is that all there is to it?

Does everyone just dig out their library of string functions and parse the Categories property, trusting not to get in a muddle when multiple categories are set for a single mailitem and (heaven forbid) categories are renamed?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can choose to manipulate the comma-delimited string of Categories any way you choose. To insert a category, I usually check if the current string is null and then just assign it. If the category is not null then I append it if it doesn't already exist. To remove an item, I just replace the category name with an empty string.

#### Adding Category

```cs
 var customCat = "Custom Category";
 if (mailItem.Categories == null) // no current categories assigned
   mailItem.Categories = customCat;
 else if (!mailItem.Categories.Contains(customCat)) // insert as first assigned category
   mailItem.Categories = string.Format("{0}, {1}", customCat, mailItem.Categories);
```

#### Removing Category

```cs
var customCat = "Custom Category";
if (mailItem.Categories.Contains(customCat))
  mailItem.Categories = mailItem.Categories.Replace(string.Format("{0}, ", customCat), "").Replace(string.Format("{0}", customCat), "");
```

There are multitudes of ways to manipulate strings - they just chose to keep the serialized data structure simple underneath.

I tend to create my own Categories during Add-in startup to verify they exist. Certainly - category renaming is a concern, but if  you are ensuring that your categories exist each time your add-in loads, you can at least ensure some level of validity.

#### To manage Outlook Categories, you can use [ThisAddIn.Application.Session.Categories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._namespace.categories.aspx).

```cs
var customCat = "Custom Category";
if (Application.Session.Categories[customCat] == null)  
  Application.Session.Categories.Add(customCat, Outlook.OlCategoryColor.olCategoryColorDarkRed);
```

Comment: Hi, I just tried doing this, however the category doesn't update. It runs the instruction `mailItem.Categories = customCat;` with no problems, but it doesn't show in Outlook. Should I save or something?

Comment: You need to issue a [`MailItem.Save()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866979.aspx) to persist any metadata changes with [`MailItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861332.aspx)

Comment: FYI according to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860423(v=office.15).aspx the delimiter is localized (which is a dumb idea) `This property uses the character specified in the value name, sList, under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International in the Windows registry, as the delimiter for multiple categories.`

Comment: Note you can ensure you are using the current culture "List dilimiter" with
mailItem.Categories = $"{customCat}{System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator}  {mailItem.Categories}";

Answer (score 1):

Just to include one last information inside of the @SilverNija - MSFT post. After do something like this:

```
 var customCat = "Custom Category";
 if (mailItem.Categories == null) // no current categories assigned
   mailItem.Categories = customCat;
 else if (!mailItem.Categories.Contains(customCat)) // insert as first assigned category
   mailItem.Categories = string.Format("{0}, {1}", customCat, mailItem.Categories);
```

Don't forget and it is the most important, to update the instance of the mailItem this way:

```
mailItem.Save();
```

Because, there is an issue that sometimes a bunch of mail items are not updating when they are inside of a loop, so it worked for me to solve this problem.