# Set Outlook category on mail using Java

Tags: java, email, outlook, exchange-server

I'm trying to set custom categories on an email item programmatically using Java.

I found this: [Setting an Outlook mailitem's category programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162449/setting-an-outlook-mailitems-category-programmatically)

but I would like to do the same thing in Java. I guess some custom headers are set on the message, but I can't find information on which headers I should set. Anyone got information on this?

Answer (score 0):

[JMSG](http://www.independentsoft.de/jmsg) is Java API to create and read Outlook message files. It provides methods to set/get categories as well as many other headers.